# Spring boot and tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I would like to see a spring boot sample that lets me do:

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

I tried existing samples and following tutorials but with no luck.

Comment: Don't you just have to put the tomcat integration jars on the classpath and call `SpringApplication.run(..)` with a `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotated class?

Comment: There is a spring-boot maven plugin that let's you run from source on the command line "mvn spring-boot:run". Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the vanilla tomcat plugin supports servlet 3.0 (tomcat 7). You can probably use the tomcat7 plugin with the the war samples though (e.g. [servlet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-servlet), [jsp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp), [static](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static)).

Here's a sample plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: you're right. tomcat (6) won't handle it. but after adding plugin tomcat7:run also doesn't work

Comment: Works for me. I added the above plugin config to the JSP sample.

Comment: @piotrek I got it working adding also the `<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>` plugin, together with the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` mentioned in this answer. The `pom` in the mentioned JSP example here [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/pom.xml] does not contain the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` which I found needed to get the `mvn tomcat7:run` command working.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is not very clear about this, but I've found this concise and easy how-to to put spring boot and tomcat maven plugin all together.

https://gerrydevstory.com/2014/08/22/spring-boot-and-the-embedded-tomcat-container/

The gist of the information on the site:

- Remove spring-boot-maven-plugin `<plugin>` configuration on pom.xml
- Setup tomcat7-maven-plugin `<plugin>`

.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

- Instead of SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args), bootstrap Spring Boot using SpringBootServletInitializer instead, eg:

.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

}
```

And change the scope in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks to EpicPandaForce, he did the long explanation, my answer was just pointed the link to the how to